# my way of solving the probability question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many 2-digit numbers can be formed using the digits 0, 1, 3, 5, 7 and 9 if repetitions are allowed.

my work:

3x5x7
1x0x9

answer = 6 digit numbers can be formed. Is this the correct way of solving this question? If not, whats the correct solution to the problem above?

Comment: Your work seems to have a factor $0$, so the result should be $0$.  You are asked for two digit numbers, not six digit numbers.  The trick is that the first digit cannot be $0$.  How many choices for the first digit?  How many choices for the second?  It is also not a probability question.

Comment: im not sure,how would you solve this question?

Answer (score 1):

If a two digit number is required, imagine the places below
$$--$$

Now the first place has the options - $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ as it cannot start with a 0
the second place has no restriction, since repetition is allowed

Hence, number of options for first place  - 5

Number of options for second place - 6

Total numbers  = 5*6 = 30

Comment: so how is the answer 30?

Comment: You have 5 options for first place, and 6 options for second place. So, for each number I fill in the first place, there are 6 numbers I can add to my list, with each of the numbers from the list. So the total number of numbers is 6+6+6+6+6 = 30

Comment: ok so,30 two-digit numbers can be formed if repetitions allowed ,correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: their was also another question  I needed help with if you could help me with it that would be great ,i wanted to post it to ,but it wouldn't let me

Comment: Send it on chat

Comment: i cant because i dont have enough  reputation ,i only have 7 because  im new on this website ,i just found out about it this month ,i can send it here ,

Comment: heres the question: The number of ways 5 students can sit in a row of 5 adjacent seats in a movie theatre, given that one particular student, Elizabeth, must sit in the middle, is

Comment: Fix Elizabeth in the middle. Then you have to place 4 people in 4 different spots, and order is important. You can easily just forget about Elizabeth, and the problem would be equivalent to placing 4 different books on a shelf - 4!

Comment: so would the answer be 4 or  24? becasue 4!=24

Comment: 4! = 24 is the answer

Comment: hi dhanvi ,for this question:  Using the letters in the word ENGLISH, how many distinguishable 4 letter arrangements can be formed if no letters can be repeated and the first letter must be E.would the answer be 1108?